# Where to report suspected immigration offences in New York City?

Tags: united-states, new-york-city, immigration

Is it unlawful for a non-US citizen to enter the US on a tourist visa and work as a sex worker in NYC? Also, would it be considered human trafficking if she were to travel to her own country before returning to the US?

If either of these are unlawful, how would one report it to the relevant authorities?

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is illegal. If you want to report that, it is your choice.

I went to google.com and typed in "report immigration offense in new york" the first response was 1-866-347-2423 from usa.gov

I am not from USA, but I would imagine that is the correct number.